# Ajax does not working with php on the same page in wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

my code is working fine in localhost but when I put the code in a page in Wordpress it's not working anymore.
Can somebody help me?
Were do I save this php file and how do i call it in ajax?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["check_c"]) && $_POST["check_c"] != "") {

include_once 'db.php';
$cityname = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['check_c']);
$sql_check_result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM land WHERE 
cityname='$cityname' LIMIT 1");
$check_result = mysql_num_rows($sql_check_result);
if ($check_result < 1) {
    echo '<strong>' . $cityname . '</strong> is OK';
    exit();
} else {
    echo '<strong>' . $cityname . '</strong> NOT OK';
    exit();
}
}
?>

<script>

function check_city(){
var status =document.getElementById("result");
var c = document.getElementById("city").value;
if(c != ""){
    status.innerHTML = 'checking...';
    var cxr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    cxr.open("POST", "wordpress/page1", true);
    cxr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-
    urlencoded");
    cxr.onreadystatechange =function() {
        if(cxr.readyState == 4 && cxr.status == 200){
            status.innerHTML = cxr.responseText;
        }

    }
    var r = "check_c="+c;
    cxr.send(r);

}
    }
</script>   

City: <input id="city" name="city" onBlur="check_city()"><span id="result">
</span><br>
```

Comment: Don't use the old, deprecated and insecure `mysql_*`-functions. Use `pdo` or `mysqli` instead.

Comment: _"when I put the code in a page in Wordpress"_ - How do you put it in Wordpress? Where is your Wordpress installation? Not on localhost? And what does _"it's not working"_ mean? Any error messages? Checked the error log?

Comment: I have my wordpress on localhost so i can test my code first.

Comment: Ok. I got confused, since you said _"working fine in localhost"_ but not in Wordpress. Either way. You need to do some debugging, like checking the console, error log etc. And you _really_ need to tell us what _"not working"_ means.

Comment: OK, Ajax load the php file but load also the header php-file, Warning : mysql(i) jquery() expects at least 2 parameters. Mysql(i)_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Comment: No wonder. You're posting to `wordpress/page1` (which I'm guessing that your PHP-file isn't called), so Wordpress will load everything like it's any other page call. How it's implemented depends on your theme. If you just want to call a PHP-script without any WP at all, post to the actual file: `path/to/file.php`. Or better yet, read up on [how to use Wordpress built in ajax functionality](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action))

Comment: Page1 was just an example, the link is the same as where i put the ajax and php file

Comment: You have two issues (which should actually be two different questions) 1. The header get's included. Is the above PHP _all_ there is in that file or does it contain more code and/or html? 2. You get a mysql-error. You need to copy the _exact_ error message you get. The one you pasted into your comment is not exactly what it says. (mysql(i) jquery() isn't a thing). And since you're using the deprecated `mysql_*`-functions, the error shouldn't say that mysqli has an issue (unless the error comes from somewhere else).

Comment: The problem with the parameters is the connection with the db

Comment: The problem with the parameters is the connection with the db. I didn't use the $wpdb.    global $db;  $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id FROM land WERE city='$city' LIMIT 1");      Now I have to change the next row but I don't now how to do that.

Comment: Well, I wish you all the luck, but since you're not really answering my questions, there isn't much I can do. I'm out.